# pci 0000:00:04.1: BAR 13: failed to assign [io size 0x1000]

Tags: kernel, drivers, bios

I heard that NVMe device doesn't need MMIO space, so dmesg will show this error:

`pci 0000:00:04.1: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]`

since BIOS didn't allocate MMIO for it but OS will try to allocate for it. ( is this description correct ?)

Why NVMe device doesn't need any MMIO space? Does an SSD have the same situation? ( don't need MMIO )